# Howto show filled form with existing data on symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I'm trying to present a symfony2 filled form using existing data from the database.
What I want is to update data. 
For this I want to display the current data on the form.

Currently I'm getting the data and filling the form, but I think this is not the best way to do it.

```
<form>
{% for value in values %}
    <input type="text" placeholder="{{ value.name }}">
    <input type="email" placeholder="{{ value.email }}">
    ...
{% endfor %}
</form>
```

I know how to create a form with createFormBuilder and AbstractTypes, but not how to show or present this form filled with existing data from entities.

Comment: Where does your data come from, is it an entity in the database? How are you creating your form?

Comment: Symfony has a best component *Form* for generate and submitting form. Please see the official documentation and Entity type.
http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html
http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html

Comment: I know how to create a form, that's not the point. What I'm asking is how to create and show a "filled" form.
I'm getting data from a database as allways with EntityManager.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are you building the form by hand? You should only have `{{ form(form) }}`. That's why everyone is asking you where do you create it, because it's the same place as where you fill it. From the Form manual:

```
public function newAction(Request $request)
{
    // you can use a new instance of an entity or
    // get existing data from your database 
    // e.g. $task = $em->getRepository('Bundle:Task')->find(1);
    // and this data will fill your form.
    $task = new Task();
    $task->setTask('Write a blog post');
    $task->setDueDate(new \DateTime('tomorrow'));

    $form = $this->createFormBuilder($task)
        ->add('task', 'text')
        ->add('dueDate', 'date')
        ->add('save', 'submit')
        ->getForm();

    return $this->render('AcmeTaskBundle:Default:new.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));
}
```

See the call to `createFormBuilder`? That's where you input the data to your form. The data in the passed object / array will be used as the fill data for your form. Now, it's up to you to provide the wanted data, whether it's an entity from the db or an array with arbitrary data. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that´s it. I was trying the way you mention and didn´t work because I wasn´t getting the data correctly from the database, really frustrating. :D